# SQL query to join two tables help

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables one is heardt and other one is jud

In heardt i have three columns *j1* ,*j2* ,*j3*(each has one value from jcode)

In jud i have *jcode* and *jname*.

I want to display jname in 3 different Dropdown list depending on *j1* ,*j2* ,*j3*.

How do i frame my sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question as the schema seems odd.

However, it sounds like you want to get:

- Dropdown1 : Show jname where jcode is
  in a j1 cell in heardt
- Dropdown2 :
  Show jname where jcode is in a j2
  cell in heardt
- Dropdown3 : Show
  jname where jcode is in a j3 cell in
  heardt

To do that your queries could be:

```
select jname, jcode
from heardt
inner join jud ON heardt.j1 = jcode

select jname, jcode
from heardt
inner join jud ON heardt.j2 = jcode

select jname, jcode
from heardt
inner join jud ON heardt.j3 = jcode
```

An alternative, that may interest you, is if you want to get for every `heardt` row and the three jnames that match it you could do this:

```
select jud1.jname as jname1, jud2.jname as jname2, jud3.jname as jname3
from heardt
left join jud as jud1 on jud1.jcode = heardt.j1
left join jud as jud2 on jud2.jcode = heardt.j2
left join jud as jud3 on jud3.jcode = heardt.j3
```

However, a better solution would be to make tables like these (pick better naming):

```
jud table
---------
jcode
jname

heardt table
------------
unsure on the purpose of this table

dropdown table (name this after whatever your dropdowns represent, maybe this is heardt)
----------
dropdownId

dropdownjuds table
-------------
dropdownId
jcode
```

That way you could do a query like below, and you aren't storing a column per dropdown. For instance, what if you suddenly need `j4` later - with this method you could just add a new `dropdown` and relevant entries to the `dropdownjuds` table. What if the dropdowns have uneven numbers? You'd be using nulls currently I assume, but why have `j1` and `j3` columns if the row only has a `j2`? With the proposed design you'd get around this.

```
select jname 
from dropdownjuds ddj
inner join jud on ddj.jcode = jud.jcode
where dropdownId = *
```

Where * is 1 for dropdown1, 2 for dropdown2 etc.

Comment: Thank You.I want Exactly how you understood my question.

Comment: In your first suggestion for each query i can use a string to store the value and than pass it in Dropdownlist. How do i do it for the second one?

Comment: The second query isn't suitable for a single dropdownlist - how do you know if to use 'jname1' or 'jname3' right, unless you want to specifically link them up to combo boxes in your code which is bad. I would use the first queries, or my proposed schema revision.

Answer (score 0):

If you elaborate the requirement (giving some data in the table and showing your expected output in terms of the same data), it would help.

If you wish to have a query to get the names for a set of input (j1, j2, j3), in that case you shall have to have inner queries or multiple joins.

```
select h.j1, hj1.jname, hj1.jcode, h.j2, hj2.jname, hj2.jcode, h.j3, hj3.jname, hj3.jcode
from heardt as h
inner join jud as hj1 ON h.j1 = hj1.jcode
inner join jud as hj2 ON h.j2 = hj2.jcode
inner join jud as hj3 ON h.j3 = hj3.jcode
where h.j1=@myj1 and h.j2=@myj2 and h.j3=@myj3
```